# Eclipse: generate entities from MySQL - why there is DAO methods in entities?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa, entity

I am trying to generate JPA entities from MySQL. I using Hibenate. I read http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/reference001.htm .

This is part of my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ISO 3166-1 alpha-2',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `code_UNIQUE` (`code` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `street` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `psc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `countries_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_contacts_countries1_idx` (`countries_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contacts_countries1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`countries_id`)
    REFERENCES `countries` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Eclipse generate these entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c")
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String code;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Contact
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
    private List<Contact> contacts;

    public Country() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return this.contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public Contact addContact(Contact contact) {
        getContacts().add(contact);
        contact.setCountry(this);

        return contact;
    }

    public Contact removeContact(Contact contact) {
        getContacts().remove(contact);
        contact.setCountry(null);

        return contact;
    }

}
```

Class Contact looks similar.

Why there are methods "addContact" and "removeContact"? Is it good idea? I always used to CRUD dao and service class.

What is better? "addContact" / "removeContact" methods, or delete it and put this functionality to dao/service class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addContact and removeContact methods are utility method to add to/remove from the

```
private List<Contact> contacts;
```

They are not the dao alternatives. They just populate the entities. To persist/delete from actual database, you will anyways need to write DAO methods.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it. It's not a bug it's a feature ;-)